# Sort an NsmutableDictionary Alphabetically

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nsmutabledictionary

I have a `dictionary` in which, for a single key(for example key "0") there are a `key value pair data`.The keys are like name, id,p_id. I want to sort the `NSMutableDictionary` for the values related to the Key "name". The data in the `dictionary` is as follows,

```
 0 =     {
        id = 12;
        name = "Accounts ";
        "p_id" = 13222071;
    };
    1 =     {
        id = 13;
        name = "consultant";
        "p_id" = 15121211;
    };
    2 =     {
        id = 11;
        name = "Tania";
        "p_id" = 10215921;
    };
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: NSDictionary are not sorted.

Comment: I do not want to sort the Dictionary for keys,i want to sort it for the Values related to the keys.Like i want to sort the Dictionary for value related to the key name .

Comment: @NikhilShende Sorting in any way is simply not possible for Dictionaries whether you are sorting for keys or values against them. NSDictionary stores its keys in a hash table, which is unordered by design. Since keys are unordered, the values against them would be unordered as well.

Answer (score 1):

Please try out the below code:

```
        [yourMutableArray sortUsingComparator: (NSComparator)^(NSDictionary *a, NSDictionary *b) {
             NSString *key1 = [a objectForKey: @"name"];
             NSString *key2 = [b objectForKey: @"name"];

             return [key1 compare: key2];
        }];

        NSLog(@"Sorted Array By name key : %@", yourMutableArray);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *sortedKeys = [dict.allKeys sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary *d1, NSDictionary *d2) {
    return [d1[@"name"] compare:d2[@"name"]];
}];

NSArray *objects = [dict objectsForKeys:sortedKeys notFoundMarker:[NSNull null]];
```

Comment: I do not want to sort the Dictionary for keys,i want to sort it for the Values related to the keys.Like i want to sort the Dictionary for value related to the key name .

Comment: since we're sorting based on d1[@"name"] and d2[@"name"], the sort is done on the VALUE of the dictionary. The keys will be in order of the sorted values which you will then retrieve with objectsForKeys:sortedKeys. Did you try running the snippet?

Answer (score 0):

`Dictionaries` are not sorted, and doesn't resemble any order. What you should do is to getAll the `keys` first. Then apply a `sort method` on the keys, then request the objects according to the ordered keys.

E.g:

```
NSArray *keys = [dictionary allKeys];
NSArray *sortedKeys = <sort the keys according to your preferred method>
```

Now you can iterate the Dictionary from the order of the array sortedKeys.

Answer (score 0):

While it has been made abundantly clear that Dictionaries can't be sorted and rightfully so, that does not mean the ends you are aiming for can't be achieved. This code will do that for you:

```
    NSArray *arrayOfDicts = dic.allValues; //Now we got all the values. Each value itself is a dictionary so what we get here is an array of dictionaries

    NSSortDescriptor *nameDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES]; //Create sort descriptor for key name
    NSArray *sortingDesc = [NSArray arrayWithObject:nameDescriptor];
    NSArray *sortedArray = [arrayOfDicts sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortingDesc]; //Get sorted array based on name

    NSMutableDictionary *kindaSortedDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    int keyForDict=0;
    for(NSDictionary *valDict in sortedArray)
    {
        [kindaSortedDict setObject:valDict forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",keyForDict]]; //Set values to our new dic which will be kind of sorted as the keys will be assigned to right objects
        keyForDict++;
    }

    //Now you can simply get sorted array of keys from kindaSortedDic and results for them will always be sorted alphabetically. Alternatively you can just skip all that bother and directly use sortedArray
```

I have added comments in code to help you understand that.

For accessing sorted values I'd do this:

```
NSArray *sortedKeys = [kindaSortedDict.allKeys sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:
                    @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"intValue" 
                                                    ascending:YES]]];
for(NSString *key in sortedKeys)
{
   NSDictionary *valDict = [kindaSortedDict objectForKey: key];
   NSLog(@"Dict is: %@ for key: %@",valDict,key);
}
```